# How can we rotate an Image in circular motion in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

How can we rotate an image in circular motion like free rotate in any direction in python. Is it possible? If yes then how can I do that? Thanks!

What I tried, I used opencv library to rotate an image by 1 degree on mouse click.
but that's not working out. It rotates slowly and needs to click for every 1 degree rotate.

Here is the code for that

```
 import cv2 as cv
 #import numpy as np

 DEF_ANGLE = 0

 def click_to_rotate(event,x,y,flags,param):
 global DEF_ANGLE,DEF_ANGLE1
 if event == cv.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
    DEF_ANGLE += 1


 elif event == cv.EVENT_FLAG_RBUTTON:
    DEF_ANGLE -= 1


 cv.namedWindow('window')
 img = cv.imread('4.2.04.tiff')    #put any image here with path
 cv.setMouseCallback('window',click_to_rotate)



 while(True):
 num_rows, num_cols = img.shape[:2]
 rotation_matrix = 
 cv.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2,num_rows/2),DEF_ANGLE,1) 
 img_rotation = cv.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))
 cv.imshow('window',img_rotation)
 k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 if k == 27:
     break

 cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tested out your code and it seems to work fine. Can you throw some more light on what you expect?

Comment: @JeruLuke hey thanks for reply. Mnnnn here is the one example

    https://www196.lunapic.com/editor/?action=photo-spread

just go to the link above its online editor tool in that from left side at the 6th option rotate image. Try that rotate tool to rotate the image. Just upload any image there. You will get it what I am trying to say.

Comment: @Niranjankulkarni [check](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/#comment-460962) this out.

Comment: @iPhoton Well I tried that before...but that is not what I am trying to do!!!
 if you try that example which I have answered to Jeru Luke with the link you will get it.

Comment: Your code is doing the same rotation (rotate around an anchor point) as the link you've mentioned in the comments. What is the exact problem?

Comment: @Niranjankulkarni so you want rotate every tile in an image randomly?

Comment: @zindarod What I am doing is, I click on image every time to rotate it. What I want is just drag(by holding your click on an image rotate in any direction Rotate Right or Rotate left) an image in circular motion to rotate it. And in that link it shows exactly what I want. I hope you will get it what I am saying. if not take a look in online tool  www196.lunapic.com/editor/?action=photo-spread Thanks

Comment: @JeruLuke somewhat like that!

Comment: @Niranjankulkarni That is a **BIG** ask but not impossible !!

Comment: @JeruLuke I am confused. Does he want a slider button to drag for rotation (as in the link) or does he want to rotate individual tiles?

Comment: @zindarod if that is the case it can be done using track bars!

Comment: @JeruLuke Either of those operations can be done. We just need to know what exactly he is after.

Comment: @JeruLuke Please check my new code down below Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working demo of your expectation:

```
import cv2 as cv

DEF_ANGLE = 0
pressed_left = False
pressed_right = False

def click_to_rotate(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global DEF_ANGLE, DEF_ANGLE1, pressed_left, pressed_right

    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        pressed_left = True
        DEF_ANGLE += 1

    elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        #print('x,y',x,y)
        if(pressed_left):
            DEF_ANGLE += 1 

    if event == cv.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        pressed_right = True
        DEF_ANGLE -= 1

    elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        #print('x,y',x,y)
        if(pressed_right):
            DEF_ANGLE -= 1 

    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        pressed_left = False

    elif event == cv.EVENT_RBUTTONUP:
        pressed_right = False

cv.namedWindow('window')
path = 'C:/Users/selwyn77/Desktop/'
img = cv.imread(path + 'ch.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx = 0.1, fy = 0.1) 
cv.setMouseCallback('window', click_to_rotate)

while(True):
    num_rows, num_cols = img.shape[:2]
    rotation_matrix = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2, num_rows/2), DEF_ANGLE, 1)
    img_rotation = cv.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))
    cv.imshow('window', img_rotation)
    k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I used two global variables each for left and right rotations.

Answer (score 1):

@JeruLuke hey....Some how I manged to do that :D
Check this code

```
import cv2 as cv
#import numpy as np

DEF_ANGLE = 0
pressed = False

def click_to_rotate(event,x,y,flags,param):
global DEF_ANGLE,DEF_ANGLE1,pressed
if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    pressed = True
    #DEF_ANGLE += 1

elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    #print('x,y',x,y)
    if(pressed):
        DEF_ANGLE += 1

elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    pressed = False


cv.namedWindow('window')
img = cv.imread('4.2.04.tiff')    #put any image here with path
cv.setMouseCallback('window',click_to_rotate)

while(True):
   num_rows, num_cols = img.shape[:2]
   rotation_matrix = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2, num_rows/2), 
   DEF_ANGLE, 1)
img_rotation = cv.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))
cv.imshow('window',img_rotation)
k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now here, surely is a difference between my previous code and this code.
and now there is a problem, when I move my mouse it rotates in one direction only i.e. it rotates right only. How to rotate left using same logic??

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is impressive. Maybe you can incorporate the use of right mouse button to rotate it the other way round (`cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP` and `cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN`)

Comment: Check out the answer. I hope it suits your requirement!!